# JavaScript Object to Array of Objects with 'name' key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here my initial object :

```
partners {
  0: "Proxy"
  2: "Skate"
  8: "Air"
}
```

I want to have this :

```
partners [
  0:{name: "Proxy"}
  1:{name: "Skate"}
  2:{name: "Air"}
]
```

I tried this without success :

```
var newArray = Object.values(this.initialObject).map(function (value) {
                                return { ['name']: obj[value] };
                            });
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: And the question/problem is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Return value should be `return {name: value}`

Comment: Always check the error console.

Comment: `Object.values(partners).map(name => ({name}))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` does not need to be wrapped in `[' ']` as it is a key nor do you need to use `obj` to get the value as `value` is the variable passed by the function.

Try this instead:

```js
var partners = {
    0: "Proxy",
    2: "Skate",
    8: "Air"
}

var newArray = Object.values(partners).map(function (value) {
    return {name: value};
});

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const a = {
  0: "Proxy",
  2: "Skate",
  8: "Air"
}

const result = Object.values(a).map((value) => {
    return { name: value };
});
console.log(result)
```

This will do it, you had to replace the obj[value] with value and replace ['name'] with simple name.

Answer (score 3):

```
partners ={
  0: "Proxy"
  2: "Skate"
  8: "Air"
} 

var newpartners=[];
    Object.keys(partners).map(item=>{
      newpartners.push({name:partners[item]})
    })

console.log(newpartners);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use the following methods code

```js
var partners = {
    0: "Proxy",
    2: "Skate",
    8: "Air"
}
var arr = [];
var keys = Object.keys(partners);
var values = Object.values(partners);

keys.forEach((ele, indx) => {
    arr.push({ "name": values[indx] });
})

console.log(arr);
```

```js
var partners = {
    0: "Proxy",
    2: "Skate",
    8: "Air"
}

var newArray = Object.values(partners).map(function (value) {
    return { name : value };
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, just using an array as a container for the final desired output, and loop over the original object with `for ... in` loop. Hope this helps. :)

```
var p = {
  "0": "Proxy",
  "2": "Skate",
  "8": "Air"
}
var a = [];
for(var key in p){
 if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   a.push({name: p[key]})
  }

}
console.log(a)
```

Another way to loop through an object is to use `Object.entries` method, This method return an array of arrays, each array contain the key and the value

```
const fruits = {
  apple: 28,
  orange: 17,
  pear: 54,
}

const entries = Object.entries(fruits)
console.log(entries)
// [
//   [apple, 28],
//   [orange, 17],
//   [pear, 54]
// ]
```

So, in your case you can try something like this :

```
const entries = Object.entries(p);
var a = [];
for (const [key, value] of entries) {

  a.push({name: value})
}
```

Comment: You should describe your code to make it more effective long term.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the param `name` from the handler.

```
Object.values(this.initialObject).map(name => ({name}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
 var tempPartners=[];
    for (x in partners) {
    var obj=JSON.parse(`{"name":"`+partners[x]+`"}`);
    tempPartners.push(obj);
    }
console.log(tempPartners);
```

The output will be like

```
 0: {name: "Proxy"}
    1: {name: "Skate"}
    2: {name: "Air"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var partners = {"Proxy", "Skate","Air" };
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i<=partners.length; i++){
    newArray.push({Name: element[i]});
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: If his initial object is this `{
  0: "Proxy"
  2: "Skate"
  8: "Air"
}`, how have you ended up having `{"Proxy", "Skate","Air" }` ?